# Internet Explorer 11 can't disable localhost cookies

Tags: localhost, cookies, internet-explorer-11

I'm developing a site and I need to test some functionalities with cookies disabled.

I'm testing on localhost.

Looks like IE 11 does not disable localhost cookies.

I have tested same code with Firefox, Chrome and Opera and they all work fine.

Is there any way to disable cookies for localhost on IE 11?
And also are my predictions are correct?

I mean does IE 11 really always enables cookies for localhost regardless of privacy settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to answer my own question in case anyone comes across same issue.

Yes it turns out that IE always sends cookies on localhost.

I don't know what kind of "brilliant mind" stands behind that dumb decision.

How do they expect their browser to be used by web developers for testing as most developers test first on localhost and testing with cookies of and on is very important in many cases.

Comment: The same issue has lead me to the verge of throwing my PC out of the window. Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when I wanted to test the behaviour of a web application without cookies.

As a workaround I added an entry to my hosts file which makes the internet explorer think that I am accessing another host, even when it is 127.0.0.1:

```
127.0.0.1 testhost.com
```

Note: the hosts file on Windows 10 is located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\` and can only be written as Administrator.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work.